# I have this code python, while running the code does not show any error but when Please click on the button does not show the result

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code python, while running the code does not show any error but when Please click on the button does not show the result

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def cal():
    l=[15,7,9,11]
    s=0
    for i in range(0,len(l)):
        s=s+l[i]
return s

b = Button(root, text="ok", command=cal())
b.pack()

label = Label(root, text=cal())
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is the callback function supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a reference to the function `command=cal` instead of storing the function's return value `command=cal()`.

Comment: @KumarPyth: Hello? It's written in the answer: `command=cal`.

Comment: That still won't change th text, `st = StringVar();label = Label(root, textvariable=st)`, you can set the label in the callback function, `st.set(s)`

Comment: That's right of course.

Comment: Oh yeah, op still has quite a few issues in their code, but this fixes the question in their post. The rest is left as an exercise to the reader.